# Disable use of AsyncTask, using custom AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, class-visibility

I have the following implementation of `AsyncTask`, allowing multiple `AsyncTask`s to run concurrently:

```
public abstract class MyAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    public AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeCompat(Params... params) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            return executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
        } else {
            return execute(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Now to avoid confusion and accidental use of the normal `AsyncTask`, I would like to block access from my code to:

- The `AsyncTask` class, only `MyAsyncTask` should be used.
- The `execute()` function in `MyAsyncTask`.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea of doing this would be a bit different. Instead of extending the `AsyncTask` class, you can create a method that takes as a parameter the `AsyncTask` you want to use. Here is an example:

```
public void executeAsyncTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    } else {
        asyncTask.execute(params);
    }
}
```

With this you just need to instantiate the AsyncTask you want to use without worrying about the problems you mentioned since you will be extending the `Android's` `AsyncTask` class having overriden the `execute` method the way you want. So lets say that you have defined an `AsyncTask` named `customAsyncTask`, to execute it you just call `executeAsyncTask(new customAsyncTask(your_params));` You can define the above method in a `static` class (making the method also `static`) for easier access.

Hope that helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Do not import `AsyncTask` and only import your `MyAsyncTask` class.  That way your class is the only available option.

I suppose you could overwrite the AsyncTask method in your main file. You must have a new class file for your MyAsyncTask, however, or it will not inherit it correctly.

Comment: Eclipse will automatically import any missing classes, so that is not an option.

Comment: There's really no way to block a public class natively in java.

Comment: I suppose you could overwrite the AsyncTask method in your main file.  You must have a new class file for your MyAsyncTask, however, or it will not inherit it correctly.