# App dies on startup

Tags: android

When I start my app, I start an `AsyncTask` to do some downloading. This can take a while.
When that thread is downloading the data, I am already listening for location updates. When I receive a new location, I start a new `AsyncTask` to do some processing. However, this class depends on the downloaded data, so it has to wait until the downloading is done:

```
public void setLocation(Location location) throws IOException {
    Logger.log("New location - calculating nearest stations");
    if (!initialStationsRead) {
        Logger.log("Location update waiting for stations to be read");
        while (!initialStationsRead)
            ;
        Logger.log("Location update done waiting");
    }
    /* Do the processing */
}
```

The first thread sets `initialStationsRead` to `true` when it's done, so the second thread can pick up after that. This all works fine on my test devices.

However, I received an email from a user telling me that the app won't start. The loading screen appeared, and after 10-12 seconds disappeared without a warning. He uses a HTC One S.

This is the logcat he sent me:

```
07-05 22:11:04.938: W/dalvikvm(19961): threadid=2: spin on suspend #2 threadid=11 (pcf=1)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961): "GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 RUNNABLE
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d5c580 self=0x1669ae8
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | sysTid=19965 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21931384
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=1
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961): "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE JIT
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40f90588 self=0x1b35b00
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | sysTid=19991 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=29193008
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=287 stm=1 core=1
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.data.Data.setLocation(Data.java:~102)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.TreinVerkeer$SetLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(TreinVerkeer.java:408)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.TreinVerkeer$SetLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(TreinVerkeer.java:1)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 22:11:04.938: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-05 22:11:05.629: D/WifiStateMachine(436): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -32
07-05 22:11:05.689: W/dalvikvm(19961): threadid=2: spin on suspend #3 threadid=11 (pcf=1)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961): "GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 RUNNABLE
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d5c580 self=0x1669ae8
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | sysTid=19965 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21931384
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=1
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961): "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE JIT
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40f90588 self=0x1b35b00
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | sysTid=19991 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=29193008
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=362 stm=1 core=1
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.data.Data.setLocation(Data.java:~102)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.TreinVerkeer$SetLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(TreinVerkeer.java:408)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.TreinVerkeer$SetLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(TreinVerkeer.java:1)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 22:11:05.689: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-05 22:11:05.719: D/skia(1004): AndroidImageRef[ 0x2438190 ] releasePixel fail as lockCount=1
07-05 22:11:06.439: W/dalvikvm(19961): threadid=2: spin on suspend #4 threadid=11 (pcf=1)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961): "GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 RUNNABLE
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d5c580 self=0x1669ae8
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | sysTid=19965 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21931384
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=1
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961): "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE JIT
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40f90588 self=0x1b35b00
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | sysTid=19991 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=29193008
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=437 stm=1 core=1
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.data.Data.setLocation(Data.java:~102)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.TreinVerkeer$SetLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(TreinVerkeer.java:408)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at com.busybits.treinverkeer.TreinVerkeer$SetLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(TreinVerkeer.java:1)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 22:11:06.439: I/dalvikvm(19961):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

This is repeated x times.

Now, `Data.java:102` is the line `while(!initialStationsRead)`, so there must be going something wrong there.

What is happening, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Instead of blocking the setLocation() method until the location data is available, you can try to start the processing of the data after the downloading is finished and there is a location available. Or you can register your location updates after the downloading of the data is done.

Comment: I suspect it would be better for the consumer AsyncTask to wait rather than loop infinitely waiting for the station data. Add a Log statement to that loop to observe what is going on.

Comment: @Jan-Henk Yes I thought of that whilst writing this question, I could try that indeed.

Comment: Could use a Handler inside the async task to process the messages - say download data, pass it in via handlers into the async task...

Comment: I've sent the user the version with the suggestion of @Jan-Henk, now I'll just have to wait if this solves the problem. Any idea though why this happens on his device and not on mine or devices of other people i know?

Comment: I am just speculating right now, buty maybe there are a lot of location updates at the user's device, which will lead to a lot of blocked methods, which in turn results in this problem?

Comment: I can conclude from the logcat he sent me that is not the case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first thread sets initialStationsRead to true when it's done, so the second thread can pick up after that.

Busy loops are evil incarnate. If I had holy water handy, you'd be rather wet right now. :-)

(that also implies that I have really good holy-water throwing aim over long distances, which probably isn't the case)

Java has plenty of options for thread synchronization, and has had them for a decade-plus, from the low-level `wait()` and `notify()` on `Object` to the `java.util.concurrent` constructs like `Semaphore`. Pick one and use it, getting rid of the busy loop.

Or, follow Jan-Henk's advice and do the work serially on the same thread, based on a flag.

> Any idea though why this happens on his device and not on mine or devices of other people i know?

Well, for starters, the One S is dual-core, and so your threads may actually be running at the same time (one per core). Threading problems will be more likely to surface in multi-core environments.

Also, Angelo's answer -- posted while I was writing this -- is worth noting.

Comment: Actually, I could use some water here, it is hot as hell :) Anyways, like I commented on my question, I've implemented Jan-Henk's suggestion and sent a copy to the user. +1 for the explanation though! I will await a response from the user before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that helps but keep in mind that after `HoneyComb` (`Android 3.0`) and before `Donut` (`Android 1.6`) only one `AsyncTask` can run simultaneously, since `AsyncTask` use a thread pool pattern and the default thread pool size on these versions is 1. If you want the `AsyncTasks` you are using to run simulteneously in these versions of `Android`, you can use this code `executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...)` using the flag `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`. See this answer [of this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible/4072832#4072832) for more information. Seeing that the user that has an `HTC One S` device wich runs `Android 4.0`, maybe this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Note that the serialized executor for `execute()` only kicks in if you have `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 13 or higher, and you are running on Android 3.2 or higher.

Comment: I've indeed tackled that problem already, and already applied the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` fix. (See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229734/disable-use-of-asynctask-using-custom-asynctask) Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: I proposed a solution to your previous question. I don't know if this was what you were looking for. Hope that helps:)