# Android webview thread error

Tags: android, webview

i am trying to load the html form asset, but its loading webpage and application getting closed.The error shown is webview thread, i am not  able to understand what ia going on to throw this error.

please check the below image.

error

[image]

html snapshot
[image]

Comment: This link might help you to get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352527/app-dies-on-startup

Comment: the log file doesn't show any errors, they are normally displayed in RED.

Comment: this error on emulator or also real devices?

Comment: @TapaSave real device.

Comment: @Tuga your right. But application getting closed.

Comment: connect the `real device` to your computer, open eclipse or the code editor you use and monitor the logcat for errors.

Comment: or use aLogcat or aLogrec (search in Google Play) utilities for save logcat to file or screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android webview runs in a separate thread (worker thread),  their should be the synchronization with webview thread and threads that your spawning.